# CFScript and ColdFusion Optional Arguments

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I would like to provide optional arguments to a ColdFusion Component using only CFScript, while maintaining use of the ColdFusion QueryParam SQL.

**EXAMPLE A:** Retrieving information from a basic **user.cfm** for all users:

```
<cfset get = application.controller.getuser()>
```

**EXAMPLE B:** Optionally, using the same method.  Retrieving information from a basic **user-edit.cfm?edit=662B2709-0BA3-42DB-AD2CC29069F4A259** for a specific user:

```
<cfset get = application.controller.getuser( userUID=url.edit )>
```

**EXAMPLE C:** Alternately, using the same method to find a specific first name:

```
<cfset get = application.controller.getuser( firstname=form.firstname )>
```

**CFC ISSUE:** Below is my **controller.cfc**.  I would like to maintain the "AND userUID = :userUID" as an optional CFQueryParam that appears when requested only when requested by my script.

```
public function getuser( userUID='', password='', firstname='' ){
    var get = new query();

    // query
    get.setSQL("
        SELECT  *
        FROM    users
        WHERE   1 = 1
        AND     userUID = :userUID
        AND     firstname = :firstname
        AND     passhash = :password
        ");

    if ( len(arguments.userUID) > 0 )
        get.addParam( name = "userUID", value = "#arguments.userUID#", cfsqltype = "cf_sql_varchar" );      

    if( len(arguments.firstname) > 0 )
        get.addParam( name = "firstname", value = "#arguments.firstname#", cfsqltype = "cf_sql_varchar" );

    if ( len(arguments.password) > 0 )
        get.addParam( name = "password", value = "#arguments.password#", cfsqltype = "cf_sql_varchar" );

    return get.execute();
}
```

Comment: Use conditional logic to build a variable with your sql.  Then use that variable in your get.setSQL method.

Comment: What exactly is the "issue"? Are you asking how to build the sql string? If yes, build it conditionally, just as you do with the parameters. Then pass the final string into `setSQL(...)`. Otherwise, could you please clarify your question? Be sure to include any error messages.

Comment: In your logic, you may want to use `len(trim(arguments.userID))` (and for other variables) as written currently, a space (or multiple spaces) would get past the logic.

Comment: Also, there is no need to use `#` signs in the `addParam()` calls. You can remove the quotes and `#` and simply use: `value = arguments.password`. Lastly, are you storing the passwords in plain text (seems like you may be), if so, stop doing that. You will want to hash them before storing them.

Comment: Your whole approach here is (at best) sub-optimal, if not outright wrong. **Functions should perform a single task** - you appear to be conflating three distinct tasks here.

Comment: `controller.authenticateUser(username,password)`, `controller.getAllUsers(/*optional filter*/)`, `controller.getUser(useruid)`

Comment: Thanks everyone!  Dan and Leigh - excellent info on how this function is evaluating.  Scott - good to know on the pound-signs and no, I am not working in 1995 on the passwords.  I just wanted to know how this works.  Peter - again, just an example!  The Adobe documentation on cfscripting doesn't lend one to want switch if you know what I mean (if you see, the users and not Adobe are providing the examples).  ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this should get you started.

```
sqlString = "select * from users where 1 = 1 ";
if ( len(trim((arguments.userUID)) > 0 )
sqlString &= " AND     userUID = :userUID";
etc

get.setSQL(sqlString);
```

Note that with this answer the query will return the entire table if no arguments are provided.  That's also the case for your original code.  You might want to think about handling that situation.